# gnupg specify gpg-agent path

Tags: gnupg, python-gnupgp

I am using python-gnupg wrapper, I have copied gpg binary (`/usr/bin/gpg`) along with dependent libraries identified by `ldd gpg` command, When defining gpghome i did specify the binary path as well.

```
gpg = gnugp.GPG(gnupghome='/tmp', gpgbinary='/var/task/gpg')
```

I get below error

```
gpg: failed to start agent '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': No such file or directory
```

I have copied gpg-agent in /var/task/gpg, but it still fails because it is starting the gpg-agent from /usr/bin, How can i change the path for gpg-agent from /usr/bin to /var/task/gpg?